# Is there a way to restrict Pageable's size and page values passed to controller method by Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using following controller method

```
public String listUsers(@PageableDefault(size = 20, page = 0) Pageable pageable)
```

And obviously, we can controll page and size with query params `size` and `page`. But lets say, we want to protect ourselfs from dumping whole database in one page by user or due to tempering. Is there a limit, that can be set to Pageable object eg. `@DefaultPageableConstrains` or I have to validate size by hand?

I just would like to make use of Spring validation mechanisms like `@Valid` `@Min` or `@Max` annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default maxPageSize is 2000. This can be overriden like so:

```
@Configuration
public class PaginationConfiguration extends SpringDataWebConfiguration {
    private final int MAX_PAGE_SIZE = 200;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver =
            new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(sortResolver());

        pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.setMaxPageSize(MAX_PAGE_SIZE);

        return pageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is something I have found out as well. Maybe you will know the answer to my followup question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820935/what-is-happening-with-default-argument-resolver-when-custom-resolver-for-same-t