# What is happening with default argument resolver when custom resolver for same type is added?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

So I want to limit maximum pageable size value to 10 (example value) and I can do this like that:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setMaxPageSize(10);
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
    }
}
```

and delcare controller method like this

```
   @RequestMapping(name = "list")
    public String listUsers(@PageableDefault(size = 5, page = 0) Pageable pageable) {
```

Indeed, this will work, I wont be able to set page size to>10 but I am curious why? What is happening to Spring created `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`? Why this instance is taken into consideration and not the default one? After all, I am no replacing resolvers here, only adding a new one.

Comment: The `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that returns `true` on the `supports(MethodParameter)` is used to resolve the method parameter. If what you added returns `true` that is the one used even if the another resolver supports it. There must be something else going on here, user-added resolvers might be prioritized or Spring no longer adds its preset resolvers if a resolver of the same type exists but with that I'm not sure. Only one resolver works on every method parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Configuration phase**

When you extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and add custom resolvers in `addArgumentResolvers`, (skipping lots of configuration code) you are actually adding them to [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java#L116) `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` bean saves internally the list of all resolvers, provided during initialization.  ([WebMvcConfigurationSupport](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L558)). After that they are combined with default resolvers. And as you can see from  the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java#L618-L659), `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is not actually part of the  default resolvers list, but comes from some configuration class. And in my case (screenshot below)  the `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` configuration classes provide different version of  PageableHandler: `HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

**2. Resolvers Order**

Custom resolvers are ordered after built-in ones ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java#L195-L197)). So lets check this and call some controller, but put breakpoint in [RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java#L755) first. From here we can see the internal state of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`

[image]

I highlighted custom resolver `MyPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, registered the same way you did in your question code.

And the code that actually resolves arguments is in [HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java#L115-L145). It is simple loop and it means that the first registered `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` will be used

```
for (HandlerMethodArgumentResolver methodArgumentResolver : this.argumentResolvers)
    if (methodArgumentResolver.supportsParameter(parameter)) {
        result = methodArgumentResolver;
        this.argumentResolverCache.put(parameter, result);
        break;
    }
```

And as you can see from the source code, the result is cached and never iterated again for the same parameter type.

Comment: So basicly speaking, right now it works by an coincidence am I right? - as unrelated `@Configuration` classes processing order is undetermined, so it just happen that my configuration comes first.

Comment: @Antoniossss I think yes, every configuration been has `LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` by default, but you can use `@Order` to ensure priority for your custom configurations. So when `List<WebMvcConfigurer>`  autowired in [DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java#L48-L53), it is sorted internally according to the `order` of the beans.

Comment: As for resolvers that come from the [SpringDataWebConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/config/SpringDataWebConfiguration.java#L138-L149), i think, it is configured in such a way that if you extend from this class, override `addArgumentResolvers` and don't call super like `HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration` you don't get the "default" resolvers

Comment: Allright, all in all the right way to do it will be to use [SpringDataWebConfiguration#pageableResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/4bd8a3cfc3a242cd3d433937ece7a4905efce4c8/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/config/SpringDataWebConfiguration.java#L93-L99) and setup resolver there. Thanks for discussion

Comment: @Antoniossss yeah i think so. And you can actually modify existing bean with `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer` like [spring-boot-autoconfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/web/SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.java) does

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day a lot nicer! :). 2 hours I was digging for an aswer. Finally using this info, I was able to determine Spring to call my Handler, by removing the @RequestBody annotation from the signature.