# How to replace deprecated class method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interface, deprecated

I found a piece of code that I wanted to implement in my application. The code works fine, but has `Deprecated` methods. The code I'm talking about is:

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 20));
    argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
    super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
}

}
```

And specifically the `Deprecated` class is `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and it's method `addArgumentResolvers`. According to documentation:

> as of 5.0 WebMvcConfigurer has default methods (made possible by a Java 8 baseline) and can be implemented directly without the need for this adapter

And so I've replaced the deprecated class with a `interface` - `WebMvcConfigurer`. Problem is the interface won't allow me to use `addArgumentResolvers` method. What do I do now? Should I create an instance of the `interface`? Are there any drawbacks to using a deprecated methods?

Comment: "Are there any drawbacks to using a deprecated methods" - You should probably look up the meaning of deprecated. If you don't upgrade the library at all, then there are no "drawbacks", but it essentially means that there are no guarantees that the deprecated class or method will exist in future versions of the library, potentially breaking your code on upgrade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is happening with default argument resolver when custom resolver for same type is added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820935/what-is-happening-with-default-argument-resolver-when-custom-resolver-for-same-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawbacks to use deprecated methods is that when you'll migrate to the newer version of library, the method may be gone completely and you'll have to rewrite your code. Another thing is that usually there are reasons for library developers to deprecate methods - either they are ineffective, or lead to bad design, or (most common) have analogs.

WebMvcConfigurer according to [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) has default method `addArgumentResolvers(java.util.List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers)`. If you can't use it, check that your project supports **Java 8**.

Example how it works:

DefaultMethods.java

```
public interface DefaultMethods {   default void example(){
    System.out.println("default method call");   } }
```

DefalutMethodsTest.java

```
public class DefalutMethodsTest implements DefaultMethods{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DefalutMethodsTest().example();
  }
  @Override
  public void example() {
    System.out.println("implementer call");
    DefaultMethods.super.example(); 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
implementer call
default method call
```

Comment: It does. I just can't apply the method to `super` class.

Comment: There is no super class, because you implement an interface. Call it for this class.

Comment: If you need to _add_ some functionality to it, see the example I added.